# PayPal in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use `JMSPaymentCoreBundle` with `JMSPaymentPaypalBundle` and I can't find a clear example anywhere on how to do it.

I've done all steps specified in the documentation and I'm not able to get it working. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? How far did you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default way to create a payment instruction is through the jms_choose_payment_method form:

```
$form = $this->getFormFactory()->create('jms_choose_payment_method', null, array(
        'amount'   => 12.99,
        'currency' => 'EUR',
        'default_method' => 'payment_paypal', // Optional
        'predefined_data' => array(
            'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
                'return_url' => $this->get('router')->generate('payment_complete', array(
                    'number' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
                ), true),
                'cancel_url' => $this->get('router')->generate('payment_cancel', array(
                    'number' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
                ), true)
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

You can also create a payment instruction manually:

```
        use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\ExtendedData;
        use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\Payment;
        use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\PluginController\Result;
        use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\ActionRequiredException;
        use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\Action\VisitUrl;
        use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction;


        $extendedData = new ExtendedData();
        $extendedData->set('return_url', $this->get('router')->generate('payment_complete', array(
                'number' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
            ), true));

        $extendedData->set('cancel_url', $this->get('router')->generate('payment_cancel', array(
                'number' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
            ), true));

        $instruction = new PaymentInstruction((float)$order->getCharge() > 0 ? $order->getCharge() : $order->getAmount(), 'EUR', 'paypal_express_checkout', $extendedData);
        $this->get('payment.plugin_controller')->createPaymentInstruction($instruction);

        $order->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);
        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();
```

My payment_complete route looks like:

```
public function completeAction(Booking $order)
{
    $instruction = $order->getPaymentInstruction();
    if (($instruction->getAmount() - $instruction->getDepositedAmount()) > 0) {
        if (null === $pendingTransaction = $instruction->getPendingTransaction()) {
            $payment = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller')->createPayment($instruction->getId(), $instruction->getAmount() - $instruction->getDepositedAmount());
        } else {
            $payment = $pendingTransaction->getPayment();
        }

        $result = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller')->approveAndDeposit($payment->getId(), $payment->getTargetAmount());
        if (Result::STATUS_PENDING === $result->getStatus()) {
            $ex = $result->getPluginException();

            if ($ex instanceof ActionRequiredException) {
                $action = $ex->getAction();

                if ($action instanceof VisitUrl) {
                    return new RedirectResponse($action->getUrl());
                }

                throw $ex;
            }
        } else if (Result::STATUS_SUCCESS !== $result->getStatus()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Transaction was not successful: '.$result->getReasonCode());
        }
    }

    $order->setTransactionAmount((float)$order->getAmount());
    $creditPurchased = (float)$order->getCharge() > (float)$order->getAmount() ? (float)$order->getCharge() - (float)$order->getAmount() : 0;
    $em->persist($order);
    $em->flush();
```

I've got it running going through http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSPaymentCoreBundle/master/usage

Comment: I need just a form where you can say the amount you want to pay and a "pay now" button.. :D

I think i'm not understanding what's exactly the data flow for all this payment bundle. Why a payment instruction is NOT the same as an order??

is this correct?

1- Render a form with an input to write the amount (creating and flushing an order).
2- Render (inside the previous form) the payment_details route too with the "choose payment method" form, submitting the post data and the orderNumber.
3- Update the Order entity and flush everything else.

Answer (score 19):

[Payum bundle](http://payum.org/doc#PayumBundle) supports jms payments via the [bridge](http://payum.org/doc#JMSPaymentBridge). The links describes how to get started.

Usage of the bundle gives you several advantages:

- Secured capture action.
- Have credit card form, can ask user for credit card
- Ability to easy setup IPN. Notify action is also secured.
- Built-in support of all omnipay gateways (25 +), jms plugins (+ 10) and payum native libs.
- Payum paypal lib supports recurring payment and digital goods out of the box.
- Storages integrated into payment process so you do not have worry about data that might be lost.
- Domain friendly. Indeed Payum provide some models but it does not restrict you to use them.
- It already supports PSR-0 logger. In dev it logs executed payum actions, to easy debug (Visit symfony profile logs tab).
- It is possible setup several payments (one paypal account for EU and one for US for example)
- Extremely customizable. Add your custom payum actions, or extensions, or storages.
- There is a symfony sandbox ([code](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox)|[web](http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com/)) to help you to start.

P.S. It is not the full list of features.